# Deterministic Random Number Streams in C++ STL

Tags: c++, stl, random

I want to supply a number, and then receive a set of random numbers.  However, I want those numbers to be the same regardless of which computer I run it on (assuming I supply the same seed).

Basically my question is: in C++, if I make use of `rand()`, but supply `srand()` with a user-defined seed rather than the current time, will I be able to generate the same random number stream on any computer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`srand()` & `rand()` are not part of the STL. They're actually part of the C runtime.
Yes, they will produce the same results as long as it's the same implementation of `srand()/rand()`.

Depending on your needs, you might want to consider using [Boost.Random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/random/index.html). It provides several high-quality random number generators.

Comment: Gonna have to say +1 on Boost.Random. Works great and they even have specific deterministic classes.

Answer (score 7):

There are dozens of [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom%5Fnumber%5Fgenerator)s available as libraries. Pick one. I tend to use [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister).

By using an externally supplied library, you bypass the risk of a weird or buggy implementation of your language's library `rand()`. As long as your platforms all conform to the same mathematical semantics, you'll get consistent results.

MT is a favorite of mine because I'm a physicist, and I use these things for Monte Carlo, where the guarantee of equal-distribution to high dimensions is important. But *don't use MT as a cryptographic PRNG!*

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not use MT for crypto?  Mind sharing a link?  (It's an honest question, I'm not trying to be snarky :-)

Comment: It's easily predicted from small number of know outputs. There is a link in the wikipedia article.

Comment: Hmmm..there *doesn't* seem to be a link in the wikipedia article. In that case, I don't have one close to hand. Sorry.

Comment: The original paper includes some commentary on it. Sec 1.6 http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/ARTICLES/mt.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the implementations of `rand()` are the same, yes.

The easiest way to ensure this is to include a known rand() implementation with your program - either included in your project's source code or in the form of a library you can manage.

Comment: "Every" is a BIG word.  Qualifying this with "Most" instead of "Every" is necessary.  Most modern RNG's are designed to work consistently across most families of 32-bit Hardware.  But that says nothing about 64-bit machines or rare peculiar hardware.

Comment: That's why I said you need to have a copy of rand() you can control or at least predict.

Comment: Fair enough :-)  The only other thing to make sure of is that it's portable in terms of datatypes to all your target architectures.

Comment: I misread your answer, and have retracted my first comment.  My apologies :-)

Answer (score 2):

Write your own pseudorandom number routine. There are a lot of algorithms documented on the internet, and they have a number of applications where rand isn't good enough (e.g. [Perlin Noise](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm)).

Try these links for starters:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator

Answer (score 2):

No, the ANSI C standard *only* specifies that `rand()` must produce a stream of random integers between 0 and RAND_MAX, which must be at least 32767 ([source](http://members.cox.net/srice1/random/crandom.html)).  This stream must be deterministic only in that, for a given implementation on a given machine, it must produce the same integer stream given the same seed.

You want a portable PRNG.  [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) (many implementations linked at the bottom) is pretty portable, as is [Ben Pfaff's homegrown C99-compliant PRNG](http://www.stanford.edu/~blp/writings/clc/random.html).  [Boost.Random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/random/index.html) should be fine too; as you're writing your code in C++, using Boost doesn't limit your choice of platforms much (although some "lesser" (i.e. non-compliant) compilers may have trouble with its heavy use of template metaprogramming).  This is only really a problem for low-volume embedded platforms and perhaps novel research architectures, so if by "any computer" you mean "any x86/PPC/ARM/SPARC/Alpha/etc. platform that GCC targets", any of the above should do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you supply with srand with the same seed, you will get the same results. That's pretty much the definition of a seed in terms of pseudo random number generators.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  For a given seed (starting value), the sequence of numbers that rand() returns will always be the same.

Comment: You should qualify this with "a given implementation of rand()". No two PRNGs are guaranteed to produce the same sequence.